# Using Google Analytics API, is it possible to filter on a dimension and a custom variable at the same time?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a webapp that hosts several thousand subdomain sites under a single Google Analytics property. I'm in the process of upgrading my tracking tags from the old `ga.js` system to the new `analytics.js`-based system (Universal Analytics).

In my old setup, when the tracking code got instantiated, I would send a site id to GA as a custom variable. Then, when pulling analytics for my users, I would simply filter on site ID as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
    ids=ga:76149262&
    start-date=2015-01-18&
    end-date=2015-01-20&
    metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:pageviewsPerVisit,ga:bounces&dimensions=ga:date&
    filters=ga:customVarValue1==f6853365a940330037c3aceff36de412&
    max-results=100
```

In the new **Universal Analytics** system, there are no custom variables, as these have been replaced by dimensions. No problem. I've created a new dimension called **siteHash** and I've been submitting it along with each page request. What's more, I'm able to query this with only one *tiny* modification to my API request above:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
    ids=ga:76149262&
    start-date=2015-01-18&
    end-date=2015-01-20&
    metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:pageviewsPerVisit,ga:bounces&dimensions=ga:date&
    filters=ga:dimension1==f6853365a940330037c3aceff36de412&
    max-results=100
```

As you can see, I've just changed `ga:customVarValue1` to `ga:dimension1`, and everything works.

Here's the issue: Once I push this code change to production, a lot of my sites will start to have a mixture of old data and new data. The old data will be tagged with the custom variable and the new data will be tagged with the new  dimension. How can I query on both `ga:dimension1` and `ga:customVarValue1` at the same time within the same query?

I've tried creating an "OR" query as described here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#OR

This yields a filter parameter that looks like this:

`ga:dimension1==f6853365a940330037c3aceff36de412,ga:customVarValue1==f6853365a940330037c3aceff36de412`

Unfortunately, doing an API request with this filter yields no data. Does anyone know why? Is there a prohibition on filtering on dimensions and custom variables at the same time?

Assuming this is, for some reason, impossible. Is there any way to convert already collected custom variable data into dimension data? If I were able to do this, I could just query the API and only filter on dimensions since all of the old custom variable data would now be dimension data.

Comment: why not make two requests?

Comment: You get no data because OR statement works only if you are using single dimension. As it is stated in help page you've pointed "operator may NOT be used to combine dimensions and metrics in the same expression". So it is imposible to create such filter. All the metrics you ask for are additive. So why don't you, as DalmTo commented, create two requests and just sum it up? You would not have problem with different size of response, because if date is only dimension, you will get all possible dates in response event if metrics are equal 0.

Comment: @DalmTo: I may end up making two requests.

Comment: @TomekLechowicz Oh. I thought it was saying "operator may NOT be used to combine dimensions and metrics in the same expression" (which I'm not doing) but what they were apparently really trying to say was "operator may NOT be used to combine different dimensions or different metrics with each other in the same expression."